# Installing recommended VS Code extensions in Dev Container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

In Visual Studio Code, it is possible to recommend extensions for a project by listing them in the file `.vscode/extensions.json`.

For Dev Containers, it is possible to automatically install extensions upon creation of the container by listing them in the file `devcontainer.json`.

I would like for all the recommended extensions to be installed in the Dev Container. Is it possible to install extensions in the Dev Container based on `.vscode/extensions.json` and not have to maintain the list of extensions in two places?